# RequireJS: Can't import any module to specific one

Tags: javascript, requirejs

**Problem:** In the code below I can't import `AnotherModule` to `MyModule`:

```
define("MyModule",
    [
        'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'somepackage/AnotherModule',
        'jquery-ui'
    ],
    function($, _, Backbone, AnotherModule) {
   console.log(AnotherModule); // RefferenceError: AnotherModule is not defined
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
ReferenceError: AnotherModule is not defined
    at Object.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:2:15)
    at FrameMirror.evaluate (native)
    at Object.evaluate (<anonymous>:415:28)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:704:39)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:643:52)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame (<anonymous>:755:21)
```

**P.S.** I tried to import lots of modules to `MyModule` - the same result. That happens only with `MyModule`, another modules work well

Comment: It would still help if you *did* include AnotherModule source in your question.. Also, you're probably making things up to some extent as `console.log(AnotherModule)` wouldn't throw an exception, it would simply write "undefined". Moreover, as noted in a comment under one of your other questions: it's actually a good idea *not* to name your modules

Answer (score 0):

Do you return anything from **somepackage/AnotherModule** module?
Also, there is no need to give names your modules (you should not use the anonymous module-id "MyModule"). Just let the filename be the module name instead.

In the folder **somepackage**, add the file **AnotherModule.js**:

```
// somepackage/AnotherModule.js
define(['underscore'], function(_) {
    var AnotherModule = {};

    AnotherModule.extend = _.extend;

    return AnotherModule;
});
```

Use it from "MyModule":

```
//MyModule.js

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'somepackage/AnotherModule'], function($, _, Backbone, AnotherModule) {
    console.log('args', arguments);
    console.log('AnotherModule', AnotherModule);

    var MyModule = {};

    return MyModule;
});
```

Comment: yes, I return. Moreover I can import that module from other modules, but not from `MyModule`

Comment: Okay! I need to view more of your code. Github gist?